# custom error 27 during simulate transaction

Tags: python, transaction, liquiditypool, simulate

I keep getting this error and totally lost, can someone please help?

The code is in python, i am using raydium pool keys to send a simulated transaction so i can calculate the price for my swap.

Instructions i am passing:

```
def make_simulate_pool_info_instruction(accounts, mint, ctx):
        accountProgramId = ctx.get_account_info_json_parsed(Pubkey.from_string(mint))
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = accountProgramId.value.owner
        keys = [
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["amm_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["authority"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["open_orders"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["base_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["quote_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["lp_mint"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),     
        ]
        data = POOL_INFO_LAYOUT.build(
            dict(
                instruction=12,
                simulate_type=0
            )
        )
        return Instruction(AMM_PROGRAM_ID, data, keys)
```

Rest of Python code:

```
pool_keys = fetch_pool_keys(mint)

sim_inst = make_simulate_pool_info_instruction(pool_keys, mint, solana_client)

recent_blockhash = solana_client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash
txn = Transaction(fee_payer=sender.pubkey(), recent_blockhash=recent_blockhash)

txn.add(sim_inst)
txn.sign(sender)
temp = solana_client.simulate_transaction(txn)
```

Error that i keep getting:

```
 [
'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 invoke [1]',
"Program log: panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom(27)', src/processor.rs:4251:85", 
'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 consumed 6492 of 200000 compute units',
'Program 675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8 failed: SBF program panicked'
   ]
```

I got the code from an old github repo of 2022 for transaction simulation.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks to raydium sdk... by adding this to instructions: AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts['event_queue'], is_signer=False, is_writable=False)

Comment: Great! Can you post the solution an an answer and mark it as accepted?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Ademola, back then my rep was less so thats why i commented under the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed it,** thanks to raydium sdk... by adding this to instructions: `AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts['event_queue'], is_signer=False, is_writable=False)`

Complete instructions:

```
def make_simulate_pool_info_instruction(accounts, mint, ctx):
        accountProgramId = ctx.get_account_info_json_parsed(Pubkey.from_string(mint))
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = accountProgramId.value.owner
        keys = [
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["amm_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["authority"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["open_orders"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["base_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["quote_vault"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["lp_mint"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts["market_id"], is_signer=False, is_writable=False),
        AccountMeta(pubkey=accounts['event_queue'], is_signer=False, is_writable=False)     
        ]
        data = POOL_INFO_LAYOUT.build(
            dict(
                instruction=12,
                simulate_type=0
            )
        )
        return Instruction(AMM_PROGRAM_ID, data, keys)
```

Comment: Good stuff. Thanks!

Comment: What is POOL_INFO_LAYOUT @Ademola?

Comment: @randomdatascientist used to create instructions data type. for more details you may look at it in raydium-sdk>liquidity which is in typescript or my github project "raydium-convert-SOLorTokens"